# Getting today's UNIX timestamp with Calendar

Tags: java

I'm trying to get today's UNIX timestamp (seconds elapsed since 01/01/1970) at 00:00:00 with Java's Calendar:

```
public long getTodayTimestamp() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());      
    c.set(  c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            0, 0, 0
    );
    return c.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
}
```

The problem is it returns 1409608800 for today (September 1st), but when I try to convert it with some converter (for example http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) I get `Mon, 01 Sep 2014 22:00:00 GMT` which is midnight September 2nd my local time. Basically the method is returning the timestamp 24 hours ahead of what I need.

Where did I screw up?

Comment: Because of "issues"? Why can't you just use `Date` or `System`?

Comment: Because of issues it would take me half an hour to explain. EDIT: oops, sorry, that part was left from when the question had a wider focus. Of course I can use Date or whatever in a method, but how? And why would it work better than Calendar in this case?

Comment: You may set the time zone? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone,%20java.util.Locale%29)

Comment: Setting the time zone has no effect. The time on the device is September 2nd at this moment, and it is returning midnight of September 3rd.

Comment: Set the time zone of the `Calendar` to GMT+0

Comment: Setting the time zone of the calendar to GMT+0 worked. How come? And what happens if the user is in PST or something? And maybe you should put it as an answer.

Comment: @TimSim [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is Jan 1 1970 at 00:00 UTC.

Comment: `Calendar` maintains a concept of Time Zone, this means that if you set the time zone to `GMT+0`, you remove any local details.  For example, right now, I'm `GMT+10`.  So normally, it would print `1409609943979`, but `GMT+0` prints `1409609943993`

Comment: Without `UTC+0` = `1409610014458`, with `1409610014472`

Answer (score 1):

The online converter returns the date UTC+0
Your are in TimeZone +2.
That means: 22:00:00 (UTC+0) is 00:00:00 (UTC+2) in your timezone
so, when i am not wrong (i hope so), everything seems to be correct.

**EDIT:**
The problem in your case:
the method getTodayTimestamp() returns the timestamp in UTC+0
(getCalendar.getTimeInMillis returns in UTC+0)
That means 00:00:00 in your locale (UTC+2) is 22:00:00 in UTC+0
this is what the converter is showing!

see here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()

Comment: But the method should be returning the beginning of the current day, not the beginning of the next day.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the unix time the hard way :-)

at least you won't have to struggle with locales and etc

```
public class GetUnixTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("date");
        ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process pr = ps.start();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sw.write(line);
        }
        pr.waitFor();
        in.close();
        sw.flush();
        sw.close();

        System.out.println(">"+sw.toString()+"<"); //parse this guy
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll have to struggle with system locales, your programm will behave differently for some environment variables and so on...

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Instant   // Represent a moment in UTC.
.now()              // Capture current moment in UTC.
.getEpochSecond()   // Get the whole seconds component within an `Instant`, ignoring any fractional second.
```

## Details

The [answer by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25613519/642706) appears to be correct.

## Avoid j.u.Calendar

Date-time work is much easier with a decent library instead of the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. Either use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8. Both of these libraries handle time zones explicitly and clearly.

## *java.time*

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Apparently you want a count of whole seconds since the epoch references of first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;  // Get the whole seconds component within an `Instant`, ignoring any fractional second.
```

## *Joda-Time*

Example in Joda-Time 2.4.

```
DateTime nowParis = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
DateTime nowUtc = nowParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
long millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch = nowParis.getMillis(); // Some result when called on either nowParis or nowUtc.
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch = ( millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch / 1000L );
```

Call `toString` on those DateTime objects to verify their value.

Or in a single line.

```
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch = ( DateTime.now().getMillis() / 1000L );
```

Since we want only seconds since epoch of the current moment, the time zone does not matter.